# Bash scripting, react immediately to signals

Tags: bash

I have a shell script which runs very large simulation binaries. This becomes problematic when I want to request some output of variables in the script. For instance, when I run 10 large simulations, I want to be able to print which iteration I am on without having to wait a minute or two for the current simulation to terminate.

Currently, I am using the `trap` command. However, the script does not react immediately to signals but will only execute the binded function when the current iteration terminates. I will post the code if anyone needs it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start threads for each `large` thing you're going to run.  Have those threads dump results somewhere, then you have your `main` method free waiting to interrogate the results on the fly.

Comment: Hmm, would it be better to just create one thread which does the simulations instead of spawning a new one for each? Because the order matters and if I spawn multiple threads per run, then the order cannot be guaranteed.

Comment: In addition, when mentioning threads, I have not found any tutorials about it. Are you talking about &? I thought that was for a separate process.

Comment: It is. Shell scripts do not use threads; they can only start additional processes.